# Aggregate function not working properly in R

Tags: r, aggregate, average

I am trying to use the aggregate function to get 100 Hz data into 1 minute averages. However, when I use this function the 1-min averages are incorrect. A sample of the data is below. I am using the following code to calculate the 1-min values. The code does not break but the calculations are incorrect.

```
aggregate(list(X = df$`Gyroscope X`,
                   Y = df$`Gyroscope Y`,
                        Z = df$`Gyroscope Z`),
          list(minofday = cut(df$Timestamp, "1 min")),mean)

                  Timestamp Gyroscope X Gyroscope Y Gyroscope Z
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0000000 41.381838   -21.667482  -118.896492
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0100000 48.046268   -12.399903  -110.917976
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0200000 49.102786   -7.36084    -106.485602
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0300000 44.338382   -9.215699   -102.296759
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0400000 34.724123   -11.308594  -96.108404
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0500000 19.622804   -15.225221  -88.122564
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0600000 13.240968   -26.539308  -85.274663
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0700000 13.397218   -31.933596  -80.127568
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0800000 16.333009   -29.663088  -73.027348
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0900000 17.384645   -29.745485  -67.694096
2018-07-10T10:25:00.1000000 16.546632   -30.08423   -67.565922
```

Comment: Your data does not vary by the minute, so is your expected output just one row with average of all rows? What output did you get with your code? and what is your expected output?

Comment: For a start, do you know what is class / type of your d$Timestamp? It will influence the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming OP's data varies by the min (note the modified data), here is how to do it with base R and `dplyr`:

```
df$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

aggregate(list(X = df$Gyroscope_X,
               Y = df$Gyroscope_Y,
               Z = df$Gyroscope_Z),
          list(minofday = cut(df$Timestamp, "1 min")), mean)
```

or a more concise way:

```
aggregate(. ~ minofday, mean, data = cbind(setNames(df[,-1], c("X", "Y", "Z")), 
                                           minofday = cut(df$Timestamp, "1 min")))
```

**Result:**

```
             minofday        X          Y          Z
1 2018-07-10 10:24:00 48.57453  -9.880371 -108.70179
2 2018-07-10 10:25:00 27.78422 -19.314983  -95.13774
3 2018-07-10 10:26:00 16.85883 -29.704286  -70.36072
4 2018-07-10 10:27:00 16.54663 -30.084230  -67.56592
```

With `lubridate` and `summarize_all` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(Timestamp = ymd_hms(Timestamp)) %>%
  group_by(minofday = cut(Timestamp, "1 min")) %>%
  summarize_all(mean) %>%
  select(-Timestamp)
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  minofday            Gyroscope_X Gyroscope_Y Gyroscope_Z
  <fct>                     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 2018-07-10 10:24:00        48.6       -9.88      -109. 
2 2018-07-10 10:25:00        27.8      -19.3        -95.1
3 2018-07-10 10:26:00        16.9      -29.7        -70.4
4 2018-07-10 10:27:00        16.5      -30.1        -67.6
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = " Timestamp  Gyroscope_X Gyroscope_Y Gyroscope_Z
2018-07-10T10:25:00.0000000 41.381838   -21.667482  -118.896492
                 2018-07-10T10:24:00.0100000 48.046268   -12.399903  -110.917976
                 2018-07-10T10:24:00.0200000 49.102786   -7.36084    -106.485602
                 2018-07-10T10:25:00.0300000 44.338382   -9.215699   -102.296759
                 2018-07-10T10:25:00.0400000 34.724123   -11.308594  -96.108404
                 2018-07-10T10:25:00.0500000 19.622804   -15.225221  -88.122564
                 2018-07-10T10:25:00.0600000 13.240968   -26.539308  -85.274663
                 2018-07-10T10:25:00.0700000 13.397218   -31.933596  -80.127568
                 2018-07-10T10:26:00.0800000 16.333009   -29.663088  -73.027348
                 2018-07-10T10:26:00.0900000 17.384645   -29.745485  -67.694096
                 2018-07-10T10:27:00.1000000 16.546632   -30.08423   -67.565922", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Plus one for including the original way with aggregate, as was asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with timestamps the xts package has a lot of functions that can help you. For rolling up timestamps `period.apply` can help you out. The `endpoints` part can roll up the data from microseconds all the way up to years.

```
# don't load the timestamp column that one goes to the order.by part
df1_xts <- xts(df1[, -1], order.by = df1$Timestamp)

# roll up to seconds.
period.apply(df1_xts, endpoints(df1_xts, on = "mins"), colMeans)

                    Gyroscope_X Gyroscope_Y Gyroscope_Z
2018-07-10 10:25:00    28.55624   -20.46759   -90.59249
```

If you timestamp column is not yet a date time object you can use this:

```
df1$Timestamp <- strptime(df1$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Timestamp = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 
0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1), min = c(25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), hour = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), mday = c(10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), mon = c(6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), year = c(118L, 118L, 
118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L, 118L), wday = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(190L, 190L, 
190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L, 190L), isdst = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("CEST", "CEST", 
"CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", "CEST", 
"CEST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), 
    Gyroscope_X = c(41.381838, 48.046268, 49.102786, 44.338382, 
    34.724123, 19.622804, 13.240968, 13.397218, 16.333009, 17.384645, 
    16.546632), Gyroscope_Y = c(-21.667482, -12.399903, -7.36084, 
    -9.215699, -11.308594, -15.225221, -26.539308, -31.933596, 
    -29.663088, -29.745485, -30.08423), Gyroscope_Z = c(-118.896492, 
    -110.917976, -106.485602, -102.296759, -96.108404, -88.122564, 
    -85.274663, -80.127568, -73.027348, -67.694096, -67.565922
    )), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```